# Jquery create variable equal ajax data, then work with jquery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to use the variable name equal the json post comeback data, then use jquery autocomplete, Can i do like that ? and why that error

```
var name=[];

$.post(url,{name:'name'},function(data){
 getdata(data);
}

function getdata(data){
  name=data;
 }

$('#textbox').autocomplete({
 source:name
})
```

Comment: jQuery constructive with callback events. you cant use variable in outer part. Use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with success attribute.

Comment: can u show the example ? pls

Comment: Check the duplicated question